# Windows 10 iot deploy to Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: windows, deployment, iot

Kind of a weird issue here.  I have developed a REST web server using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and have the latest version of the SDK.  This application works fine when run in Debug mode through Visual Studio.  When I switch to Release and Deploy the application, everything appears to run fine and the application is installed and I can start it.  Once started, the application does not respond to any requests.  I get a the message "The minwinpc page is not working" and "minwinpc" did not send any data.

I have tried changing the boot options on the Pi to headless since this is a headless app.  I have also added it to the StartupApp and rebooted.  I'm not seeing any error messages and can't seem to find any documentation around logs or events that might be logged that would give me a clue to what is going on.

Any suggestions or advice are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you could try going to the Windows 10 IoT Core browser based settings and start the Visual Studio debugger.

[image]

This is on port 8080 and will require you to login with the admin credentials.

I'd also recommend the Windows IoT Remote Client from the Windows Store if you aren't using it already.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I found that if I packaged the app through the Store packager and deployed it manually it works fine.